# In django, I want to get a specific element and its a few neighbors in the query set which is already sorted

Tags: python, django, database, models

In my database, I have a book of users and i want to rank them according to their score (an attribute of the user), but i only want to get a few neighbors of a specific user knowing that user's id. For example, the two users whose score is just higher than him and two lower. I don't need to know all the rank list, only partial of it. Is there any more efficient way to do this than travelling through the list and locate the element? I would really appreciate any help.

This is the model.py.

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    openid = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

And here is the query: objects = User.objects.all().order_by('-score')

```
def get_partial_ranklist(openid, objects):
    l = objects.len()
    entries = []
    n = 0
    for item in objects:
        if item.openid == openid:
            break
        else:
            n += 1
    if n == 0:
        indexlist = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    elif n == l - 1 or n == l - 2:
        indexlist = [l - 4, l - 3, l - 2, l - 1]
    else:
        indexlist = [n - 1, n, n + 1, n + 2]
    if l <= 4:
        indexlist = range(l)
    for i in indexlist:
        entry_object = objects[i]
        entry = {
            "openid": entry_object.openid,
            "nickname": entry_object.nickname,
            "score": entry_object.score_today,
            "rank": i+1
        }
        entries.append(entry)
    return entries
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. This is my first time to raise a question and i really hope to do better next time...

Answer (score 0):

suppose your have your User `models`:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField()  # score

    def __str__(self):
        return self.score
```

then in the query:

```
the_id = 3  # you said this one you already know
_score = User.objects.get(id=the_id).score
_list = User.objects.filter(score__gt=_score)[:2] + User.objects.filter(score__lt=_score)[:2]
```

the `_list` is what you want.

as the official document suggets: [Limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, its much more brief than mine. What about its efficiency, compared to my method?